Filling Cells in an Excel Worksheet Based On The Value in a Specific Cell
I'm trying to automate a data input task, but the format of the incoming data is somewhat tricky. WHat comes in is a CSV file which looks like the table below.
        ATLANTIC SPIRIT             
        Looe                
Vessel  Species     Size        Kg      Date            Location
        POLLACK     2           2.5     23/04/2024  
        POLLACK     3           18.8    23/04/2024  
        POLLACK     41          5.4     23/04/2024  
        LING        3           1.9     23/04/2024  
        WHITING     2           0.4     23/04/2024  

        BEADY EYE               
        Plymouth                
Vessel  Species     Size        Kg      Date            Location
        BASS        4           15.7    23/04/2024  
        BASS        5           3.2     23/04/2024  

        BOY JACK                
        Plymouth                
Vessel  Species         Size    Kg      Date            Location    
        PLAICE          1       0.8     23/04/2024  
        BLONDE RAY      1       14.3    23/04/2024  
        BLONDE RAY      3       1.6     23/04/2024  
        SPOTTED RAY     5       1.2     23/04/2024  
        THORNBACK RAY   1       6.3     23/04/2024  
        THORNBACK RAY   2       15.7    23/04/2024  
        THORNBACK RAY   3       10.9    23/04/2024  
        THORNBACK RAY   4       2.6     23/04/2024  
        LOBSTER         1       2.7     23/04/2024  
        LOBSTER         2       1.1     23/04/2024  
        RAY BACKS       1       42.1    23/04/2024

I want to fill in the values under Vessel and Location based on values already in the data. WHat I want to end up with would look like this:
        ATLANTIC SPIRIT             
        Looe                
Vessel              Species     Size        Kg      Date            Location
ATLANTIC SPIRIT     POLLACK     2           2.5     23/04/2024      Looe
ATLANTIC SPIRIT     POLLACK     3           18.8    23/04/2024      Looe
ATLANTIC SPIRIT     POLLACK     41          5.4     23/04/2024      Looe
ATLANTIC SPIRIT     LING        3           1.9     23/04/2024      Looe    
ATLANTIC SPIRIT     WHITING     2           0.4     23/04/2024      Looe

        BEADY EYE               
        Plymouth                
Vessel              Species     Size        Kg      Date            Location
BEADY EYE           BASS        4           15.7    23/04/2024      Plymouth
BEADY EYE           BASS        5           3.2     23/04/2024      Plymouth

        BOY JACK                
        Plymouth                
Vessel              Species         Size    Kg      Date            Location    
BOY JACK            PLAICE          1       0.8     23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            BLONDE RAY      1       14.3    23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            BLONDE RAY      3       1.6     23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            SPOTTED RAY     5       1.2     23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            THORNBACK RAY   1       6.3     23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            THORNBACK RAY   2       15.7    23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            THORNBACK RAY   3       10.9    23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            THORNBACK RAY   4       2.6     23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            LOBSTER         1       2.7     23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            LOBSTER         2       1.1     23/04/2024      Plymouth
BOY JACK            RAY BACKS       1       42.1    23/04/2024      Plymouth

The vessel and location information is always in the same column, but there can be any number of rows between the different sections. I tried using offsets and Vlookup, but nothing has even come close to working.
Am I just on a hiding to nothing trying to do this or is there an approach I haven't thought of which could work?

You've tagged the question with VBA so please post the code you got, what errors are you getting or where are you stuck

I would do this with a simple piece of code:
Loop over all your data. Look at the column where the vessel/location are defined at the top of each block (I assume that this is column B).
Save vessel name, and, at the next row, the location, into variables (I named them vessel and location).
For the next rows, write the vessel and the location into the according cells of that row (I assume column A and F).
If you find an empty row, you know that a new block of data start - reset the variables, and the whole process starts again.
Sub testSub()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim row As Long, lastRow as long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row  ' Get number of rows
        Dim vessel As String, location As String        
        For row = 1 To lastRow
            Dim cellValue As Variant
            cellValue = .Cells(row, 2)
            If cellValue = "" Then
                ' A new block starts
                vessel = ""
                location = ""
            ElseIf vessel = "" Then
                ' First row of block: read Vessel
                vessel = cellValue
            ElseIf location = "" Then
                ' Second row of block: read Location
                location = cellValue
            Else
                If .Cells(row, "A") = "" Then .Cells(row, "A") = vessel
                If .Cells(row, "F") = "" Then .Cells(row, "F") = location
            End If
        Next row
    End With
End Sub


Thanks! I've adjusted your code to fit with the real-world sheet rather than the simplified version I posted here, but in essence, it works perfectly!

Another workaround:
Sub Repl()

lastrow = Cells(rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To lastrow

    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        Cells(i, 1) = vessel
        Cells(i, 6) = loca
    Else
        vessel = Cells(i, 2).Offset(-2)
        loca = Cells(i, 2).Offset(-1)
        If i <> 3 Then
            Range(Cells(i - 3, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)).ClearContents
            Range(Cells(i - 3, 6), Cells(i - 1, 6)).ClearContents
        End If
    End If


Next i
End Sub

